# Doubt on scope in loops

Tags: c++, loops

just have a question to ask regarding loops.

```
r=1000000.0;
for (i=0;i<laser_count;i++)
{
 if(this->laser_ranges[i][0] !=-1)
  {
   r= this->laser_ranges[i][0];
  }
 else
 {
   this->laser_ranges[i][0]=r;
 }
}
```

My question here is if `laser_ranges[i][0] = -1` then it is always equal to `1000000.0`. Am i right to say this? or will `r` change accordingly to the loop iteration?

Comment: Is that C++? Best to be explicit about what language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `typeof` `r` and `laser_ranges[][]` are same then --> yes, you are correct to say this *only first time* (**Edit**: which is a very special case). Usually `r` **might** change based on the values of `laser_ranges[i][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

`r` will change accordingly if the condition `this->laser_ranges[i][0] != -1` satisfies. `r` value otherwise depends on value at the index `[i][0]`.